# How to avoid unexpected newlines in quoted arguments

Tags: bash, variables, spaces

Maybe someone can explain to me the following unexpected results when working with bash and multi-word parameters? When I pass such a `echo` parameter without quotes, I get:

```
> for i in *.jpg; do tmp=`basename -s .jpg $i`; echo $tmp; done       
25 Chaos auf Schloss Burgeck
26 Die kaiserliche Urkunde
[...]
```

But when I add quotes, I get the following result:

```
> for i in *.jpg; do tmp=`basename -s .jpg $i`; echo "$tmp"; done     
25
Chaos
auf
Schloss
Burgeck
26
Die
kaiserliche
Urkunde
[...]
```

What is going on? Both outputs are unusable for further processing such as with `mdkir`.

Comment: if your files have spaces in the names, then the right tool for this is **find**, not globbing.

Comment: The reason you are seeing different output is because with quotes, the special characters such as \n \t etc, are being respected.

Comment: @MatiasBarrios I beg to differ. Processing paths with spaces and especially newlines returned by `find` is way harder than using globbing. `find` is also slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule of thumb: *Always* quote your variables unless you know what your are doing.

In your second command you only quoted one variable. `$i` was still unquoted and therefore subject to bash's word splitting. So, in the first iteration the `basename` command did not receive one argument `25 Chaos auf Schloss Burgeck.jpg` but the five arguments `25`, `Chaos`, `auf`, `Schloss`, and `Burgeck.jpg`. For each argument `basename` prints one line.

In the completely unquoted variant of your command this was no problem as the newlines where removed by bash during word splitting of `$tmp`. `echo` then inserted spaces such that (by chance) the final result was correct again. Hoewever, if your file names contained multiple subsequent spaces or special symbols like `*` the result would have been off in the unquoted variant too.

Corrected version of your script:

```
for i in *.jpg; do tmp=$(basename -s .jpg "$i"); echo "$tmp"; done
```

Which is equivalent to

```
for i in *.jpg; do echo "${i%.jpg}"; done
```